Injectivity of a convolution operator
Let $p,\mu,\nu$ be probability density functions on
$\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(y-x) \nu(y) \, dy=\mu(x).
$$ Now, consider the operator $T:L^2(\mu)\to L^2(\nu)$ such that $$ Tf=f*p.$$ Note that $f*p(x)$ is well defined for almost every $x$ as using the Jensen inequality one gets
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} (|f|*p)^2(x)\nu(x) \, dx \le \int_{\mathbb{R}}f^2(y)\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(x-y)\nu(x) \, dx \, dy =\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^2(y)\mu(y)<\infty.
$$
Edit
Let us assume that $p,\mu,\nu$ has non-vanishing (everywhere) Fourier transforms. Let us also assume that $p,\mu,\nu$ are infinitely divisible densities.
Question: Can we prove that $T$ is injective?

“Fourier transform of $p$ is non-zero almost everywhere“?

@FedorPetrov: what if $\nu$ has a non-trivial zero-set? It is possible that $f*p$ is not zero as a function but is equivalent to $0$ as an element of $L^2(\nu)$.

Well, in "almost everywhere" a measure must be specified, but something like that should be true

Condition $pf \neq 0$ for any $0\neq f \in L_2(\mu)$ is equivalent to $pg \neq 0$ for any $0 \neq g \in V=\frac{\chi_{\mu \neq 0}}{\sqrt{\mu}} L_2(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is a Lebesgue measure. To pass to the Fourier transform $\hat{p} \cdot \hat{g}$ we should be able to multiply Fourier images. So one should make sense of $\hat{p} \cdot \hat{g} $ for any $0\neq g \in F(V)$ to make use of Fourier transform.

Additionally, if $\mu = (1+|x|^2)^{-1}$, then $g$ might be equal to $e^{ikx}$, which would make $\hat{g}$ proportional to a delta function at any point $k$. If $\hat{p}$ is smooth, one can see that almost everywhere invertibility is not enough.

Thanks everyone for your comments. If we assume that $p,\mu,\nu$ have non-vanishing Fourier transforms everywhere, can we prove the injectivity?

@ChristianRemling: The inequality follows due to Jensen's inequality. I have added that in the statement.

The operator $T$ would probably have to be defined (in the usual way) through a limiting procedure, using the boundedness you established. If, say $\mu(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ near $x=0$, then very singular functions $f$ are in $L^2(\mu)$ and I don't think one can make sense of $f*p$ directly.

Let $V(\mu)=\sqrt{\mu} L_2\subset L_1$ (with Lebesgue measure) and $V'(\mu)$ be a dual of $V'(\mu)$ with respect to pairing $(f,v) = \int f v dx$. The set $V'(\mu)$ can be thought of as $\frac{\chi_{\operatorname{ess-sup}\mu}}{\sqrt{\mu}} L_2$ which we can associate with $L_2(\mu)$.
We can define Fourier transform on $V'(\mu)$ the usual way:
$$
(F(f), v) = (f, F(v)),\quad v\in F^{-1}(V(\mu)).
$$ We have $F(V'(\mu)) = (F(V(\mu))'$.
Note that $p\in L_1$, so $F(p)\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is a regular function.  But to have an equality $F(p*g)=F(p)F(g)$ we need $F(p)w \in F^{-1}(V(\nu))$ for any $w \in F^{-1}(V(\nu))$, or equivalently, $\tilde{p}*v \in V(\mu)$ for any $v \in V(\nu)$, here $\tilde{p}(x)=p(-x)$, since then we would have
$$
\begin{align}
&(F(p*g), w) = (p*g, F(w)) = (g, \tilde{p}*F(w)) 
= (g,FF^{-1}(\tilde{p}*F(w))) \\ 
& = (F(g),
F(p)w) = (F(g)F(p),w). 
\end{align}
$$
As you noted, due to the fact that
$$
\int p(y-x)\nu(y)dy = \int p(-y)\nu(x-y)dy\mu(x)
$$ we get $p*g \in V'(\nu)$ for any $g \in V'(\mu)$. Using the same equality we can obtain
$$
\begin{align} 
|(v*\tilde{p})(x)|^2  &\leq \left( \int \sqrt{\nu(x-y)} \sqrt{p(-y)}|u(x-y)| \sqrt{p(-y)} dy \right)^2 \\ &\leq \left(\int p(y-x) \nu(y)dy\right) \left(\int|u(x-y)|^2 p(-y) dy\right) \\
&= \mu(x) |s(x)|^2,
\end{align} \label{1}\tag{$*$}
$$
where $v=\sqrt{\nu} u \in V(\nu)$, $s \in L_2$. Therefore $v*p \in V(\mu)$.
Now, in order to divide by $F(p)$ in $F(p)F(g)=0$, in addition to $F(p)(\xi)\neq 0$ at any point $\xi$ we need $\frac{1}{F(p)}w \in F^{-1}(V(\nu))$ for any $w \in F^{-1}(V(\mu ))$, or equivalently $F(\frac{1}{F(p)})*v \in V(\nu)$ for any $v \in V(\mu)$. From $\int p(y-x)\nu(y)dy =\mu(x)$ we have $\frac{1}{F(\tilde{p})}F(\mu) = F(\nu)$. Note that $F^{-1}(\frac{1}{F(\tilde{p})}) = F(\frac{1}{F^{-1}(\tilde{p})}) = F(\frac{1}{F(p)})$. Therefore
$$
 \int F(\frac{1}{F(p)})(x-y) \mu(y) dy = \nu(x).
$$
Similar to inequality \eqref{1} for $\tilde{p}$ replaced with $F(\frac{1}{F(p)})$ and $\nu$ replaced with $\mu$ we get $F(\frac{1}{F(p)}) *v \in V(\nu)$ for any $v \in V(\mu)$. So indeed $\frac{1}{F(p)}w \in F^{-1}(V(\nu))$ for any $w \in F^{-1}(V(\mu ))$. Thus, $T$ is injective if $F(p)(\xi)\neq 0$ at any point.

@ChristianRemling You are right, thanks for pointing out. It should have been $\sqrt{\mu} L_2 \subset L_1$. This condition is needed to define Fourier transform on 'test functions' $V(\mu)$, and it is well defined on $L_1$. I'll edit accordingly.

Thank you. I have one more concern, which is perhaps really the same as my comment above on the OP's question: If I understand your argument correctly, you assume that $F(p)F(g)=0$ and then conclude that $F(g)=0$. But is it actually clear that $F(p*g)=F(p)F(g)$? More to the point, the convolution cannot really be made sense of directly for arbitrary $g\in V'(\mu)$ if $\mu$ vanishes to high order somewhere because then $V'(\mu)$ contains functions $g$ that are very far from being locally integrable.

@ChristianRemling First of all, OP already showed that $p*g$ is well defined for any $g \in V'(\mu)$. Even though $g$ can be highly singular, it is still a function, and multiplying it by $p(y-x)$ makes sense and the whole expression is integrable which is shown in the inequality in OP's question.

@ChristianRemling Secondly, to prove that $F(pg)=F(p)F(g)$ is what this whole thing is about. In order for this expression to be well defined we need every step in $(F(pg), F^{-1}v) = (p*g, v) = (g, \tilde{p}*v)$ $= (g, FF^{-1} (\tilde{p}*v) =$ $(F(g), F(p) F^{-1}(v)) = (F(g)F(p), F^{-1}(v))$ to make sense, here $\tilde{p}(x)= p(-x)$ (I may be missing a sign). I'll edit an answer to make that point more clear, and correct some misprints and signs in the arguments too.

@ChristianRemling And sorry for an off-topic, why do I not see your previous comments? Is this a bug?

The comment I was referring to is on the question (not your answer). And yes, the OP did show how to interpret $pg$, but it is not as $(pg)(x)=\int p(y) g(x-y), dy$, but rather by an approximation procedure (the OP's calculation assumes that the itnegral converges, which is not true in general, but only on a dense set, say $g\in C_0^{\infty}$).

It's the same as (say) defining the Fourier transform on $L^2$: the formula $\int f(x) e^{i\xi x}, dx$ makes sense on a dense set and defines a bounded operator there, and this lets one extend to $L^2$, but the FT of an $L^2$ function is not defined by this integral, for the simple reason that it need not converge.

(Sorry for swamping you with comments, this is the last one.) That $p*g$ is not defined in terms of the integral in general is also clear from my $g(x)=e^{1/x^2}$ (locally) example, when the integral will clearly not converge for most (or any) $x$ for typical $p$.

Yes, I think you are right about that. At least I don't see why the expression should be integrable, I shoudn't have said it in previous comment. Also note that 'typical $p$' is quite restrictive, e.g. if $\nu=\mu$ and $F(\mu)=F(\nu) $ do not vanish at any point, then $F(p) = 1$ and delta function is not a density.

@ChristianRemling Also note that an alternative way to understand $p*g$ is to define it as a generalized function from $V'(\nu)$ via $\tilde{p}*v$ for test function. Using continuity one can see that both definitions are the same

Let $p$, $\mu$, and $\nu$ be infinitely divisible probability density functions on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the given convolution equation. Consider the operator $T: L^2(\mu) \to L^2(\nu)$ defined by $Tf = f * p$. To prove injectivity, assume $Tf = 0$. Taking the Fourier transform, we have $\mathcal{F}(Tf) = \mathcal{F}(f) \cdot \mathcal{F}(p) = 0$. Since $p$ is a probability density, $\mathcal{F}(p)(0) = 1$, and we assume that $\mathcal{F}(p)$ is non-vanishing, so $\mathcal{F}(f) = 0$ almost everywhere.
Now, since $p$, $\mu$, and $\nu$ are infinitely divisible, there exist continuous functions $\psi$, $\phi$, and $\chi$ such that $\mathcal{F}(p) = e^{\psi}$, $\mathcal{F}(\nu) = e^{\phi}$, and $\mathcal{F}(\mu) = e^{\chi}$. The convolution equation's Fourier transform yields $e^{-\psi(-\xi)} \cdot e^{\phi(\xi)} = e^{\chi(\xi)}$. Taking logarithms, we obtain $-\psi(-\xi) + \phi(\xi) = \chi(\xi)$.
Since $\mathcal{F}(Tf) = \mathcal{F}(f) \cdot e^{\psi} = 0$, if there exists a $\xi$ such that $\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi) \neq 0$, then $e^{\psi(\xi)} = 0$, which implies that $\psi(\xi)$ is undefined, contradicting the continuity of $\psi$. Therefore, $\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)$ must be zero for all $\xi$. By the injectivity of the Fourier transform, we conclude that $f = 0$ everywhere, proving the injectivity of the operator $T$.

the Fourier transform of $f$ may not be defined. Note that $f$ belongs to a weighted $L^2$ space, so $f$ may not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ or $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
